# Can google apps scripts library be shared by different spreadsheets in my account?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have several google spreadsheets in my account. I would like to create a library to be shared by all the spreadsheets in my account. Currently, the library I created can only be shared by the worksheets in a single spreadsheet. I would like to keep my library private and accessible only by the spreadsheet in my account because it is still not good enough to be shared to the public. May I know if this can be done?

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473368/google-spreadsheet-scripts-shared-across-spreadsheets-not-libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the (relatively) new  library functionality, and keep it private to just your domain (you are using google apps, right?)

Functionality is pretty good, including auto-complete for your functions, auto-generation of documentation, versioning, etc...

Here are a few links

[Google Blog Acticle](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/introducing-versions-and-libraries-in.html)

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

Hope this is what you were looking for...

Comment: I tried to create a shared library without a domain (i.e., personal Google account, not GSuite/Workspace), but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work as expected. From what I've observed, you can only use a Sheets library in a personal account if this account is _not_ the same account you used to create the library. More info on the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67898285/452587

Answer (score 0):

**This is easy now!**

- Go to the Apps Script editor from the sheet that holds the script you want to share out as a Library.
- In the sidebar, click `Project Settings` and then copy the `Script ID`.
- Go to the sheet where you want to use this code and open the editor there.
- Click the `plus button` for `Libraries`, paste in your `Script ID` and click `Look up`.
- Leave it on `HEAD` so you can immediately get changes upon saving the library.
- The `Identifier` box will be the object name that represents your library in your code.
- Click `Add` and that's it.

*Changes to the library will be available (from whatever script is using it) immediately after save but autocomplete seems to not be updated until you refresh the editor page that's accessing the library code (no need to refresh the editor page for the library).*

More info on best practices here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries