# How to resolve "This app is blocked" error for shared Google Apps Script library?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script (GAS) library that I can reuse across my Google Sheets spreadsheets. Following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#create_and_share_a_library), here's what I've done so far:

1. Created a new project in [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Enabled Google Sheets API for project in step 1
3. Set up OAuth 2.0 authentication for project in step 1

   - Credential type = User data
   - Scopes = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (I cannot use `spreadsheets.currentonly` because one method in this library requires the full `spreadsheets` scope)
   - OAuth Client ID = Web application
4. Configured OAuth consent screen

   - Publishing status = Testing
   - User type = External
   - Test users = *Gmail email I used to write the script*
5. In [Apps Script editor](https://script.google.com/):

   - Set the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project to Standard by associating it with the Project Number from step 1
   - Updated `appsscript.json` to look like this:

     ```
     {
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "dependencies": {
          "enabledAdvancedServices": [
            {
              "userSymbol": "Sheets",
              "version": "v4",
              "serviceId": "sheets"
            }
          ]
        },
        "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
        "runtimeVersion": "V8",
        "oauthScopes": [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
        ]
     }
     ```
   - Created a versioned deployment of my script following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#create_a_versioned_deployment)
   - Shared my GAS project as "Anyone on the internet with this link can view"

And here's the issue I'm facing:

1. Created a new Sheets using the same Google account that I used to create the GAS library
2. In the Scripts editor, I added my GAS library by entering the Script ID, then selected the HEAD version (it doesn't seem to matter -- all versions resulted in the same error)
3. In `Code.js`, wrote a test function that calls a function from my GAS library
4. Clicked the Run button to execute the test function; the following prompt appears:

   [image]
5. Clicked "Review permissions" and selected the Google account I used to create the GAS library

**ISSUE:** This error page is displayed:

[image]

Now the strange part: if I repeat steps 1-5 above using a *different* Google account (i.e., not the same account I used to create the GAS library), then it works! I get the expected OAuth consent screen, and after granting permissions, I'm able to use my GAS library.

**Has anyone figured out how to reuse a GAS library in a Sheets script that is under the same Google account as the one that was used to create the GAS library?**

Comment: If it works for one account (your gmail?) but not another (your work?) that is because of the way your domain permissions are set up.  Is that what happened? Or are both accounts under one domain. You could also try different security settings than "everyone can view".

Comment: @J.G. the Google account where the library works is also a personal account (not GSuite/Workspace). On the OAuth Consent screen setup page, I left the domain settings untouched.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote about this here: https://web.archive.org/web/20230207010146/https://aimanfikri.com/2022/05/09/this-app-is-blocked-error-on-google-apps-script-solution/

In summary:

1. Configure a 'standard project' on Google Cloud Platform.
2. Set user access under 'Scopes'
3. Add relevant user accounts (if you don't have an enterprise Google Workspace)
4. Change your Apps Script project to the newly configured project using the new 'project number'.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions in your blog post!

Comment: Thanks for that post, it was really helpful and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is blocked for your account, there is an easy approach to allow it. Just keep in mind that you would need to be an admin in the domain in order to run these changes. Follow this guide on [allowing apps](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177431#zippy=%2Cblock-or-allow-one-app) and complete its steps. Feel free to leave a comment if you need more help.

Comment: Jacques-Guzel Heron, what if my account is a personal account with no domains set up? I don't understand why I can use the library on other personal accounts -- the only account where it doesn't work is the personal account I used to create the library.

Comment: The account got blocked automatically due to its behaviour in order to protect the account. Some other accounts may not have got blocked. If your account got blocked, please follow my answer to restore it.

Comment: Jacques-Guzel Heron, I tried to follow the instructions in the link you provided, but I wasn't able to get past step 1: "Sign in using an administrator account, not your current account <personal@gmail.com>" -- I don't have an administrator account since this is a personal gmail account: https://i.imgur.com/BsNlmKq.png

Comment: If you are using a non-Workspace account, then I strongly suggest you to visit [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181220763) and star the issue so the developers give it more priority.

Comment: Yup, someone's looking into it right now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190879362