# Google Docs Add-On: Permission-related error "This App is blocked"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I made a Google Docs Add-On in the Script Editor. When I try to start the Add-On in Google Docs, it displays this screen after selecting and signing in the Google account:

[image: screenshot]

Not sure if it is related, in the Overview section of App Scripts, the Project OAuth Scopes are:

- Connect to an external service
- Display and run third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google applications
- View and manage documents that this application has been installed in

How can I solve this problem? or how can I debug?

The code is very similar to the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/editors/docs/quickstart/translate).

The script (`code.gs`) is as follow:

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 *
 * The above comment directs Apps Script to limit the scope of file
 * access for this add-on. It specifies that this add-on will only
 * attempt to read or modify the files in which the add-on is used,
 * and not all of the user's files. The authorization request message
 * presented to users will reflect this limited scope.
 */

/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall triggers always
 *     run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen triggers may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
 *     AuthMode.NONE.)
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('Some Title Here');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}


/**
 * Gets the text the user has selected. If there is no selection,
 * this function displays an error message.
 *
 * @return {Array.<string>} The selected text.
 */
function getSelectedText() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  var text = [];
  if (selection) {
    var elements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      if (elements[i].isPartial()) {
        var element = elements[i].getElement().asText();
        var startIndex = elements[i].getStartOffset();
        var endIndex = elements[i].getEndOffsetInclusive();

        text.push(element.getText().substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
      } else {
        var element = elements[i].getElement();
        // Only translate elements that can be edited as text; skip images and
        // other non-text elements.
        if (element.editAsText) {
          var elementText = element.asText().getText();
          // This check is necessary to exclude images, which return a blank
          // text element.
          if (elementText) {
            text.push(elementText);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (!text.length) throw new Error('Please select some text.');
  return text;
}

/**
 * Obtain the input text and pass to API
 * 
 */
function getTextAndAnalyse() {
  var text = getSelectedText().join("\n");
  var query = text.trim();
  var apiURL = "https://example.com/api/?q=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  Logger.log(response);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  if (data.error != "") throw new Error('Error connecting to API');

  return {
    result: data.result_value,
    examples: data.examples
  }
}

/**
 * Replaces the text of the current selection with the provided text, or
 * inserts text at the current cursor location. (There will always be either
 * a selection or a cursor.) If multiple elements are selected, only inserts the
 * translated text in the first element that can contain text and removes the
 * other elements.
 *
 * @param {string} newText The text with which to replace the current selection.
 */
function insertText(newText) {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var replaced = false;
    var elements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    if (elements.length === 1 && elements[0].getElement().getType() ===
        DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
      throw new Error('Can\'t insert text into an image.');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      if (elements[i].isPartial()) {
        var element = elements[i].getElement().asText();
        var startIndex = elements[i].getStartOffset();
        var endIndex = elements[i].getEndOffsetInclusive();
        element.deleteText(startIndex, endIndex);
        if (!replaced) {
          element.insertText(startIndex, newText);
          replaced = true;
        } else {
          // This block handles a selection that ends with a partial element. We
          // want to copy this partial text to the previous element so we don't
          // have a line-break before the last partial.
          var parent = element.getParent();
          var remainingText = element.getText().substring(endIndex + 1);
          parent.getPreviousSibling().asText().appendText(remainingText);
          // We cannot remove the last paragraph of a doc. If this is the case,
          // just remove the text within the last paragraph instead.
          if (parent.getNextSibling()) {
            parent.removeFromParent();
          } else {
            element.removeFromParent();
          }
        }
      } else {
        var element = elements[i].getElement();
        if (!replaced && element.editAsText) {
          // Only translate elements that can be edited as text, removing other
          // elements.
          element.clear();
          element.asText().setText(newText);
          replaced = true;
        } else {
          // We cannot remove the last paragraph of a doc. If this is the case,
          // just clear the element.
          if (element.getNextSibling()) {
            element.removeFromParent();
          } else {
            element.clear();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
    var surroundingText = cursor.getSurroundingText().getText();
    var surroundingTextOffset = cursor.getSurroundingTextOffset();

    // If the cursor follows or preceds a non-space character, insert a space
    // between the character and the translation. Otherwise, just insert the
    // translation.
    if (surroundingTextOffset > 0) {
      if (surroundingText.charAt(surroundingTextOffset - 1) != ' ') {
        newText = ' ' + newText;
      }
    }
    if (surroundingTextOffset < surroundingText.length) {
      if (surroundingText.charAt(surroundingTextOffset) != ' ') {
        newText += ' ';
      }
    }
    cursor.insertText(newText);
  }
}
```

Here is the contents of `appsscript.json`:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Shanghai",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to authenticate the script in the script editor.

Comment: Yes, I tried, same error.

Comment: Do you mean you get the same error when you try to authenticate?

Comment: What does your manifest file look like?

Comment: Do you mean `appsscript.json`? added to question

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898285/how-to-resolve-this-app-is-blocked-error-for-shared-google-apps-script-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [set the "oauthScopes" explicitly](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes) in the [manifest file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest#manifest) (appsscript.json) if you plan to use the project as an add-on.

Comment: Apparently, it works. However, I also change the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project to a newly created GCP project. Not sure which of these fixed the issue.