# Unknown issue while runing simple Google Apps Script Code

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api, issue-tracking

I developed a parsing script that gets email body and title using Google Apps Script. However, when I tried to run it, after clicking on authorize button and using my relevant email address, I received this strange issue, which is blocking me to test the script. Previously there was `Advanced` option which lets me to proceed with running a script. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**In normal circumstances, it should look like this:**

[image]

I do not know how to resolve it, kindly can you guide me to the solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go to advanced and authorize it.  If you wish to run it, it's your only choice.  And there is no way to avoid it.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I do not have advanced option, as you can see, in first screenshot.

Comment: Go back to script editor and try to run any function even a dummy function that does nothing and then authorize the script in the dialog that pops up.

Comment: did that, same issue. No "Advanced" option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898285/how-to-resolve-this-app-is-blocked-error-for-shared-google-apps-script-library

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/161759244/this-app-is-blocked-error-when-trying-to-run-sheets-api-script-in-my-own-account-and-sheets?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your script using the same account with the script ownership after signing out of all accounts or using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions allowed to run in incognito mode disabled.

If the above doesn't work, try

1. Making a copy of the script.
   This might be the easiest workaround. This might work if your script has exceeded a quota.
2. Instead of relying on the automatically set oAuth scopes, set them manually using the less permissive oAuth scopes
3. Create a Google Cloud standard to protect, enable the APIs your project requires, and add the oAuth consent script.

   - Try first setting it for private only,
   - If private only doesn't work, set it public for testing and add your email address to the authorized testers.
4. Remove the code and libraries that are no longer required.
5. Start from scratch, but this time pays special attention to writing high-quality code using the services and methods that require minimal permission, i.e., instead of GmailApp, use MailApp; if it's possible, avoid using DriveApp.

Comment: The answer solves the issue but for absolute clarity the following link shows step by step process to get it working: https://aimanfikri.com/2022/05/09/this-app-is-blocked-error-on-google-apps-script-solution/
This article really saved my day.